# Scale images if container is smaller than image nominal width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm using simple reponsive grid, http://responsive.gs/, but I need also image scaling plugin. 
Like in title, I would like to scale images if container becomes smaller that image width.

Is there jquery or JS plugin, that takes care of that?

Comment: You cannot request for plugins on SO.

Comment: As a rule, [we don't do shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). If you've tried something then, by all means, *show your attempts* and ask us for help implementing your solution. Without having made an attempt, however, this is off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I'm new to SO, will try obey the rules next time.

Comment: max-width:100% instead width:100% is the soultion. Just in case.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id='container' style="width:700px;height:300px;">
    <img src="someimage.jpg">
</div>
```

css:

```
#container img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto; /* not needed but for the sake of what is happening */
}
```

What this does is that your image fills the container in width and automatically
takes a height that wont break the aspect ratio of your image.

No need of js.

You could also experiment with the following css property: `width: inherit;` which inherits the attribute from it's parent.